# Why spring controller ,method POST throw null exception when converting the DTO class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Wine:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Wine {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private Double alcoholPercent;
    @Column
    private Double price;
    @Column
    private int quantity;
    @Column
    private Date vintage;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Company company;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Type type;
}
```

Wine DTO:

```
public class WineDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Double alcoholPercent;
    private Double price;
    private int quantity;
    private Date vintage;
    private Long companyId;
    private String companyName;
    private String companyPib;
    private String companyCountry;
    private Long typeId;
    private String typeName;
}
```

WineToWineDTO:

```
@Component
public class WineToWineDTO 
    implements Converter<Wine, WineDTO>{

    @Override
    public WineDTO convert(Wine c) {
        WineDTO dto=new WineDTO();
        dto.setId(c.getId());
        dto.setName(c.getName());
        dto.setAlcoholPercent(c.getAlcoholPercent());
        dto.setPrice(c.getPrice());
        dto.setQuantity(c.getQuantity());
        dto.setVintage(c.getVintage());
        dto.setCompanyId(c.getCompany().getId());
        dto.setCompanyName(c.getCompany().getName());
        dto.setCompanyPib(c.getCompany().getPib());
        dto.setCompanyCountry(c.getCompany().getCountry());
        dto.setTypeId(c.getType().getId());
        dto.setTypeName(c.getType().getName());


        return dto;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<WineDTO> add(
            @RequestBody WineDTO newWine){

        Wine wine = toWine.convert(newWine); 
        wineService.save(wine);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(toDTO.convert(wine),
                HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

When i request to post new object , my controller post all columnes except type id. Can someone tell me where I made a mistake? Thanks.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at org.wineShop.wine.support.WineToWineDTO.convert(WineToWineDTO.java:28)
>       at org.wineShop.wine.web.controller.ApiWineController.add(ApiWineController.java:61)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: So what is on line number 28 in your concert method? Probably some parameter you are trying to „get“ is null

Comment: Pasting your whole code here doesn't help. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: public WineDTO convert(Wine c) {
    WineDTO dto=new WineDTO();
    dto.setId(c.getId());
    dto.setName(c.getName());
    dto.setCompanyCountry(c.getCompany().getCountry());
    **dto.setTypeId(c.getType().getId());** line:28
i am sorry , this is my first app and i dont have to much expirience to explain problem. My post method convert and save everything except typeId but code is same ass other lines.
i will be greatfull if someone have some extra time to try app and help me https://github.com/nemanja1992/app

Comment: I don’t think the problem is your app. It’s rather the parameters you send in you POST request. Can you add your POST request to your answer?

Comment: seems your `Type` is null i.e. `c.getType()` is `null`, try `System.out.println( c.getType() )`

Comment: There is POST request from angularJS.
 `<label for="type">Type</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="type" ng-model="newWine.typeId">
                    <option ng-repeat="type in types" value="{{type.id}}">{{type.name}}</option>

                </select>`
I think i don't explain good enough. I have 3 class in model package. One is own class with 2 objects which are related with 2 other classes`@ManyToOne`.Code is identical to both models, but still app throw null only for one of them. Foreign id from second class from model is stored in the database normal.

Comment: I was success to solved problem, now app works great, thanks all for the effort..